# Android Spinner using ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, android, arraylist, spinner, android-spinner

I have been using values of spinner from XML string-arrays so far like:

```
Spinner karant_sp; 
karant_sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1); 
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> karant_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.karant_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
karant_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
karant_sp.setAdapter(karant_adapter);
karant_sp.setSelection(0);
karant_sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new select_karant());
```

Can I use a local java ArrayList-String as the list of items to be displayed in drop down menu?

Something like:

```
Spinner karant_sp; 
ArrayList<String> return_likes = new ArrayList<String>();
return_likes.add("Hello");
return_likes.add("world");
karant_sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1); 
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> karant_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, return_likes, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
karant_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
karant_sp.setAdapter(karant_adapter);
karant_sp.setSelection(0);
karant_sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new select_karant());
```

I know the above code doesn't work, but I would like to know something which works using ArrayList-string.

Comment: And why you are using 2 arraylist.... your arr is refering to Global arraylist but not the arraylist in which you are saving your data

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Yes. Just don't call `createFromResource()` on your `Adapter`. Use one of the constructors instead. Something like

```
ArrayAdapter<String> karant_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, return_likes);
```

This is just an example you might have to change something else to get it working depending on what isn't working. But [The ArrayAdapter Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) should help.

Comment: This is the most simplest way which can be used to populate spinner dynamically[+1]