# How to delete an Item from a Spinner Using an AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an `Activity` that deletes the item pressed on the `Spinner` using an `AlertDialog`. I'm not deleting anything yet, I just added a Toast to make sure it will work.

This is my code:

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinner);

    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    final Context context = getApplicationContext();

    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        int selectionCurrent = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (selectionCurrent != position) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.dialogtitle);

                //set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(R.string.dialogtext).setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.si,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked,
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Eliminar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }) .setNegativeButton(R.string.no
                        , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(spinner);
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
            }
            selectionCurrent = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

}
```

When I run the code, the following error is displayed: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

I tried to use `((ViewGroup)spinner.getParent()).removeView(spinner);` before the `alertDialog.show();` but it still not working.

It says: `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application`

Anyone knows how to solve the problem?

Comment: Just use `Activity context` at   `AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SpinnerActivity.this)`

Comment: @MD I did it but now it removes completly the spinner.

Comment: Where are you getting this error exactly because I don't see you trying to remove them? You might want to [look here at populating with your own list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820803/android-spinner-using-arrayliststring/19820912#19820912) then remove the item from the list and update the adapter not try to remove the view itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a variable to inflate the ArrayAdapter:

```
String[] mTestArray;
```

Get the data from resources:

```
mTestArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```

Inflate the ArrayAdapter with this array:

```
final ArrayList<String> list =new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(mTestArray));  
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

And finally remove it in your dialog:

```
final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        mTestArray , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        String item = list.get(position);


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (selectionCurrent != position) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.dialogtitle);

        //set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(R.string.dialogtext).setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.si,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        list.remove(position);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        // if this button is clicked,
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Eliminar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }) .setNegativeButton(R.string.no
                , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // if this button is clicked, do nothing
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(spinner);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
    }
    selectionCurrent = position;
}
```

Comment: i can't  inflate the array adaper because it expets an int, and mTestArray is an String[]

Comment: My fault I didn't check the way that you was creating the adapter :P, check now my changes and tell my if it's working

Comment: it keep displaying an error when an element is clicked (when the dialog is supoosed to pop). When i remove the view with ((ViewGroup)spinner.getParent()).removeView(spinner); it says that toen is null like i said in the description

Comment: Did you try with list.remove(position);adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); instead of ((ViewGroup)spinner.getParent()).removeView(spinner); to remove this element?

Comment: Yes, i did, it says I have to call removeView on the child's parent befor alert.show()

Comment: Omg.... my fault, it's because this line alertDialogBuilder.setView(spinner); you are trying set the spinner in the alert dialog but it's already attached to the main view. Do you need the spinner in the alert dialog?

Comment: No, I need the dialog to confirm the delete, I don't care about the spinner when the Dialog is on screen.

Comment: Comment this line alertDialogBuilder.setView(spinner); and run it again

Comment: Same error, don't worry man, I will do another thing if it has no solution.

Comment: Last chance, you are using final Context context = getApplicationContext(); use activity context: Context context = this;

Comment: OMG man I love you so much, I upload the full answer. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Cheers! i love it when a plan comes together :) Don't forget to support the help ;)

Comment: I can't upvote if I don't have at least 15 reputation, if you upvote my post I will be able to do it on yours.