# How to let user choose a specific year from a spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-datepicker

Hello I want the user to be able to click a spinner and choose a year from those I provide. I would provide a range from 1970 to current year, but I don't know how to implement it.

If I create a spinner and give it an array like this

```
<string-array name="spinnerItems">
    <item>1970</item>
    <item>1971</item>
</string-array>
```

Then I would need to add more than 40 items by hand, and I would need to update the app manually every year. Also the spinner onClick callback returns not the string value but the index of the string in the array, so for example 1972 would be index 3.

Also I will provide another spinner where the user will choose a year that's greater or equal of the year choosen in the first spinner.

In the end I want tos end an api request with an interval of years.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use `ArrayList` for values, like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19820912/6950238) answer.

Comment: Get current year. Use a loop to populate ArrayList from 1970 till current year .

Comment: Thanks I didnt know I could do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to create year picker  instead of creating number list of spinner

Try this

```
 ArrayList<String> years = new ArrayList<String>();
int thisYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
for (int i = 1900; i <= thisYear; i++) {
    years.add(Integer.toString(i));
}
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, years);

Spinner spinYear = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.yearspin);
spinYear.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope this will help..

Comment: What if I wanted to show the dates in descending order?

Answer (score 0):

You can add items to a spinner programmatically.

You can find out with a simple command which year we have right now and can froce the program to add numbers from e.g. 1800 to the current year to your spinner.

WARNING: Pseudo code

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
List<String> list;

list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 1800; i <= year; i++)
{
  list.add(i);
}
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Hi, I am not using DatePicker becuase I only need the year, not the day or month. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer works but I'm gonna flag as answer the guy who posted it earlier

Comment: Well I posted one minute earlier. I just asked you a question first while he just posted his answer.